# RDP unusable when using OpenVPN

Tags: openvpn, remote-desktop, rdp

I've been stuck on this problem for several days now.

I'm currently running an OpenVPN server on a self-hosted server. Our staff use this so that after logging into the VPN from remote locations, they are able to access resources in our office network. The primary use for this is to use RDP to connect to Windows machines.

We need to migrate this to the cloud. We've set up a test environment whereby AWS VPNs connect from our office to a Transit Gateway, which is connected to various VPCs. One of those VPCs contains an instance on which I am running an OpenVPN server which almost matches the configuration of the current VPN, with a few small changes. However, while RDP works perfectly fine using the current OpenVPN installation, it is unusable using the cloud hosted OpenVPN install. By unusable I mean:

- trying to play YouTube clips so that we can test framerates, the playback freezes for up to 10 seconds immediately, then the RDP session gets disconnected
- when doing anything not involving video, it usually works for a minute or two, then everything freezes, and the session gets disconnected after a while

So we are able to connect fine but clearly something isn't performing as it should, and I've tried everything I can think of. These are the details for the current, working, self-hosted OpenVPN server.

- CentOS 6.10
- OpenVPN 2.4.7

And contents of the `server.conf:`

```
local 192.168.1.103
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
cert /etc/openvpn/keys2/mycert
key /etc/openvpn/keys2/mykey

dh /etc/openvpn/keys2/dh.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

topology subnet

route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0

push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"

push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.1.1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd

client-to-client

duplicate-cn

keepalive 20 600

cipher AES-128-CBC

max-clients 100

user nobody
group nobody

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log

log         /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log

verb 4

username-as-common-name

plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn
reneg-sec 0

management localhost 17505
compress lz4
mssfix 1432
mute 10
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
key-direction 0

tcp-queue-limit 256

verify-client-cert none
```

The details of the cloud OpenVPN server:

- CentOS 7.6.1810
- OpenVPN 2.4.7

And the contents of `server.conf:`

```
port 1194

proto udp

dev tun

username-as-common-name

ca /etc/certs/ca.crt
cert /etc/certs/server.crt
key /etc/certs/server.key  

dh /etc/certs/dh2048.pem

server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0

topology subnet

push "route 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"

client-config-dir /etc/openvpn/ccd

client-to-client

duplicate-cn

keepalive 20 600

tcp-queue-limit 256

cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256

max-clients 100

user nobody
group nobody

persist-key
persist-tun

status /var/log/openvpn/openvpn-status.log

log         /var/log/openvpn/openvpn.log

verb 4

plugin /usr/lib64/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn
reneg-sec 0

compress lz4
mssfix 1432
mute 10
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
key-direction 0

verify-client-cert none
```

You can see some of the routing is different by necessity. Also, while currently the new server is using UDP, as noted below this is because I've changed this to try to resolve the issue.

This is what I've tried:

- tried both TCP and UDP (UDP never worked well for us in the office so we have used TCP for years)
- many variations in MTU settings, from 500 to 2500, in many increments
- changing the cipher to AES-128-CBC
- all available RDP colour and bandwidth settings
- various RDP display size settings
- TightVNC, which worked perfectly well, but unfortunately isn't an option as a solution. I just wanted to be sure the issue was specific to RDP

Would appreciate any ideas as I'm out of them.

Comment: Can you please add the output of `route -n` from your new RDP server? Also, which firewall do you use? pfsense by any chance?

Comment: When you say RDP server, are you saying the server I am attempting to connect to via RDP? Or the OpenVPN server?

Comment: The server is always the endpoint which is accepting connections, so yes.

Comment: It's a Windows server. Isn't route -n a Linux command?

Comment: Regarding firewalls - the current VPN server uses iptables, the new one has iptables but we use AWS security groups to manage connections, and all of the Windows machines use Windows Firewall. I'm not sure it's a firewall issue though as the sessions connect, they are just unstable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was the DoS Defense settings in the router being used by the clients we were attempting to RDP to - specifically the UDP flood defense setting (we use a DrayTek Vigor 2926). The threshold was set at 50 packets per second. Disabling this resulted in a massively improved experience so after experimenting a bit we settled on 5000 packets/second. Now works perfectly well.